# How to update ionic 2 for stable version

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have working on Ionic 2 project. I have currently install version as shown bellow. Is it the stable version of ionic 2? if not then which component version i should update?

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v7.7.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

here my `package.json`,

```
   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
```

In `console` oof google chrom its displaying `lang.js:130 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.` How to update it to `Angular2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find explicit Ionic update instructions in [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) on github.

Your installed version is stable but there're several more higher ones. So you can observe the changes and decide whether you need them and update.

You can enable production mode in Angular by importing same name function from its core and calling it before bootstrap.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'

enableProdMode()
bootstrap()
```

Comment: should i write it in `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: depends on whether you have `bootstrap()` call in there. Most probably that  you have only one `bootstrap()` in your app source. So you can find it and call `enableProdMode()` before it.